# Method reference calls wrong method

Tags: java, android, android-jack-and-jill

I'm writing an Android app and use `net.sourceforge.streamsupport:streamsupport:1.5.5`
I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 with the embedded JDK, source and target compatibility are set to 1.8.

Now I have a method reference `Light::getColor` that, when called, calls the wrong method (`Light::getMaxColorTemperature`).

```
return StreamSupport.stream(lights)
    .filter(light -> light.getColorMode().ordinal() >= ColorMode.HUE_SATURATION.ordinal()
    .findFirst()
    .map(Light::getColor)
    .orElse(Color.WHITE);
```

As seen when debugging:
[image: Debugger shows wrong method call]

If I use a lambda expression instead (`light -> light.getColor()`), the correct method is being called:

```
return StreamSupport.stream(lights)
    .filter(light -> light.getColorMode().ordinal() >= ColorMode.HUE_SATURATION.ordinal()
    .findFirst()
    .map(light -> light.getColor())
    .orElse(Color.WHITE);
```

As seen when debugging:
[image: Debugger shows correct method call]

Recompiling the whole project didn't change anything. Has anyone ever seen this? I'm not sure whether this is a streamsupport problem or an Android compiler problem, and how to figure out.

Comment: Your animated GIFs are unreadable.  Please edit the question to more clearly explain what is happening.

Comment: Being an SO user for over 6 years and with your reputation you should really know now how to properly ask questions

Comment: streamsupport, as a Jar file compiled to bytecode version 50 (Java 6), doesn't even **know** what a lambda or a method reference **is**! How could it be a factor then?

Comment: I thought an animated GIF makes it easiest to see exactly what happens, apparently that's not the case (btw. you can click the image to enlarge it, if you find it unreadable). I added the code now and explained in more detail what happens on the GIFs.

Comment: @sartorius is right, looks like a Jack bug to me. You could also try with retrolambda just to double-check. Btw., remove the `retrolambda` tag if you are really using Jack.

Comment: I guess I'm going to open a Bug on Jack then. I removed the `retrolambda` label, though now sure who added it :)

Comment: Don't bother opening a bug. Project jack is dead

Comment: You're right, I'll just go with the lambda expression for now and wait for Android Studio 3